# Multiple Owners - Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, google-compute-engine

This might not be entirely technical but google prompts me to use this community support.

So the Google Cloud account is held by one member of our team and has added the other members as the owner of the project. The billing is ideally expected to be handled from the first owner of the project. When the newly added member tries to launch a VM instance, it asks to enable billing where as the first member who initiated project is able to do so. Should the newly added members also enable billing by providing the card details? If so which user is billed? As I said, we expect the first user to be billed for this project.

Comment: Didn't quite understand, has the original owner activated billing already?

Comment: Yes, its a free account for 3 months and extended further by google for 6 months for free as a part of university project research.

Comment: @AjayNair that sounds like billing support. Google doesn't send billing support here. Everyone has billing support by default. I would go there to ask your question :) (https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing)

Comment: Thanks Patrice ! Yea I had done that already, been a day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why is it asking for billing information if that's already set up, but there can only be one billing account associated with the project, so you can carry on and just double check that the right billing account is selected in **Billing & settings** inside the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Comment: So here is the thing, I have used up my free trial much earlier. However when I map to a new gmail account, it prompts a new free signup trial option. It simply not recognizing the parent project.

Comment: Trials/Billing are per project, not account.